# Cannot create an instance of XXX from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter "yyy" to be present

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I have recently started adding strict types to all my code. For example, now I have a Doctrine entity such as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Post
{
    private string $title;

    private User $creator;

    public function __construct(string $title, User $creator)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->creator = $creator;
    }

    ...
}
```

To demonstrate a Symfony automation test case, I currently create the Post entity without supplying the user in the JSON string:

```
$client->request(
    'POST',
    '/api/post',
    [],
    [],
    [],
    json_encode([
        'title' => 'Sample title',
    ])
);
```

Because of this, I receive an error such as:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializerception\MissingConstructorArgumentsException: "Cannot create an instance of App\Entity\Post from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter "creator" to be present." at ./vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php line 313
```

This worked fine previously before I started adding the `User` type for `$creator`. The `$creator` should obviously be filled with the currently logged-in user who is using the API.

Is there any elegant way to solve this?

I noticed the Symfony serializer can accept default constructor arguments:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-constructor-arguments

Is there any way to handle this in API platform?

Answer (score 0):

It would be probably best to not set the creator manually.

Do you use `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` ([github](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions)) ?

This extension provide a lot of useful extension.

One of them is **Blameable**:

> updates string or reference fields on create, update and even property change with a string or object (e.g. user).

It is a clean way to automatically set your creator.

Once `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` is installed, you just have to enable `blameable`:

```
#stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: fr_FR
    orm:
        default:
            blameable: true
```

And use it in your entity with:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Only use annotation or attribute depending on your php version
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'created_by', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: true)]
#[Gedmo\Blameable(on: 'create')]
protected $creator;
```

I recommend using the extension, but you could also do it with your own event for example with a doctrine prePersist event listener that would set the value of `$creator`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My goal is to have type safety for the $creator by defining it as `private User $creator;`. I believe this would not solve it?

Comment: You can still have type property in this case, `private User $creator;` works as well